# Webpack Setup React + TypeScript build folder not appearing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

Hey so I do not know what I am doing wrong so I am trying to setup a React TypeScript project with webpack and babel so the source code is transpiled successfully but I am, not seeing the output directory file.

Can I please get some help on where I could be going wrong within my configurations:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/build"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlPlugin({
      filename: "index.html",
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      },
    }),
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
};
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "removeComments": true
  }
}
```

**package.json scripts**

```
{
  "name": "vid",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=beta webpack-dev-server",
    "build-prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "build-beta": "cross-env NODE_ENV=beta webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.49",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.4.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.11.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

**Here is my .babelrc file**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have a reproducible repo? If not, can you share your babel configuration?

Comment: @tmhao2005 Just added the babel config file

Comment: Hmm. Things look fine. It’s hard to say anything unless you give us the reproducible repo

Comment: That is literally everything with the source code I have not yet started coding anything I was just setting up environment before I can begin coding that is literally all that I have in project beside the ```index.html``` I can include it also if needed?

Comment: Ah. Looks like you forgot to set up the `entry` option which takes your code

Comment: Hectic!!! What a slight simple error I really could not pick that up thanks a lot man that should be my mistake